# Get Email Details through IMAP

Tags: java, android, email

I used *javax.mail* to get Emails. I'm able to fetch email details like attachments, cc, bcc, from, to, text, subject. The issue I'm facing is It is getting only that email not all the messages in that email. Let suppose A sent email to B and B replied back to A. Then again replied to B. Now if I'm login with A's profile and I fetch INBOX folder of A. I get this email and when I check `message.content()` of that email It shows only reply of B. I want to get content of first message and third message sent by A as both of the messages belong to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC conversation threads are implementation dependent cause it's not enforced nor covered in the IMAP RFC. There are some servers like gmail that lets you configure those settings. In your case it might be possible to read a specific message and then performing other IMAP verbs to retrieve the rest of the thread.

More info: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501